# My touch pad scroll works too fast in ubuntu 22.04LTS.(should we add gui for same ?)

Tags: mouse-wheel, ubuntu-22.04

I have not found id of touchpad.
I've tried [changing 2 finger touchpad scroll speed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1413750/how-to-change-2-finger-touchpad-scroll-speed-on-ubuntu-22-04#:%7E:text=Try%20the%20steps%20below%3A%201%20Run%3A%20sudo%20xinput,smooth%20scrolling%20feeling%20but%20try%20your%20own%20values.)

Comment: `sudo xinput set-prop 14 311 -1 1 1` See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44769753/which-xinput-setting-will-reverse-the-direction-of-my-mouses-scroll-wheel Also see https://www.maketecheasier.com/reverse-mouse-scrolling-direction-in-ubuntu/

Comment: should we add such a feature directly in linux gui ?

Comment: It's already there: read the second link above.